# How can I remove a command from bash completion?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

For bash completion, I would like to replace `youtube-dl` with `youtubedl`.

I can make an alias for `youtubedl`, however, both `youtube-dl` with `youtubedl` will exist.

Primarily, I just want to remove `youtube-dl` from bash completion, and create a custom function for `youtubedl`.

Comment: depending on how much you're willing to type, you could append a personal `bin` directory to your $PATH that has an executable script named `youtubedl` which simply exec's youtube-dl; you would have to type "youtubed`TAB`" to get past the dash, though.

Comment: [as described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314638/285061), if you are using at least Bash 4.4, `EXECIGNORE=*/youtube-dl` should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:** Revised answer to clarify not for non-package installs

If you installed using the manual installation which was listed first on [youtube-dl github page](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/), then this method will allow you to use `youtube-dl` with your custom name `youtubedl`, without seeing `youtube-dl` in auto-completion. On your terminal:

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin/

$ sudo mv youtube-dl youtubedl
```

You may now use it using its new name `youtubedl`, try it with the test video:

```
$ youtubedl -F 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc'
```

You may also upgrade in the future:

```
$ youtubedl -U
```

### Warranty

- Versions: `2016.01.15`, renaming and then upgrading to `2016.04.05`. See `youtube-dl --version`
- Tested only with youtube-dl installed using the manual install instructions at the [youtube-dl github page](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/), not tested with package install methods. So this answer may not work if youtube-dl was installed with a package management system that might have the install location hard-coded

### Explanation

The [youtube-dl github page](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/) instructions followed were:

```
$ sudo curl https://yt-dl.org/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
$ sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

- This downloads `youtube-dl` binary to `/usr/local/bin`.
- Paths within `$PATH` appear on auto-completion.
- `/usr/local/bin` is indeed one such path in `$PATH`, thus `youtube-dl` will appear in Bash auto-completion.

So to rename what appears in Bash auto-completion, one way is to rename the binary itself. We visit the binary's location:

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin/
```

Rename:

```
$ sudo mv youtube-dl youtubedl
```

- `/usr/local/bin` is a restricted directory, so we use `sudo`

The old name will no longer be found:

```
$ which youtube-dl
youtube-dl not found
```

And we can now refer to it by the new name:

```
$ which youtubedl
/usr/local/bin/youtubedl
```

We can test it still works, for example upgrade with `-U`:

```
$ youtubedl -U
Updating to version 2016.04.05 ...
Updated youtube-dl. Restart youtube-dl to use the new version.
```

Test its video functionality such as retrieving formats:

```
$ youtubedl -F 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc' | head
[youtube] BaW_jenozKc: Downloading webpage
[youtube] BaW_jenozKc: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] BaW_jenozKc: Extracting video information
[youtube] BaW_jenozKc: Downloading MPD manifest
[info] Available formats for BaW_jenozKc:
format code  extension  resolution note
249          webm       audio only DASH audio   47k , opus @ 50k, 57.05KiB
250          webm       audio only DASH audio   66k , opus @ 70k, 79.56KiB
171          webm       audio only DASH audio   74k , vorbis@128k (44100Hz), 89.59K
iB
140          m4a        audio only DASH audio  127k , m4a_dash container, mp4a.40.2
@128k (44100Hz), 154.06KiB
```

From the source code [`update.py`](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/update.py), line 86:

```python
filename = sys.argv[0]
```

- So this update code detects the current program's file name, thus allowing you to have `yourcustomname -U` and still successfully be able to update.

Comment: and if youtube-dl is part of a package that then gets upgraded? OP's alias will remain pointing at the previous version.

Comment: I agree with Jeff, I would like to keep it there for package upgrades, I would totally prefer an alternative if there was a way around this.

Comment: @JeffSchaller @user454038 Depending on the package manager, there might be a way to do this without it breaking on upgrade—e.g., with dpkg you can use `dpkg-divert`. (You should probably add this to your answer).

Comment: I probably should have clarified with OP how OP installed youtube-dl ... however I updated answer to clarify it is for manual installs, in case someone finds it helpful

Comment: Great answer, wish I could mark it as solved, but in this case, it has not solved my problem.
It's a shame the command has a hyphen in it, it is giving me issues by loading my .bashrc file as a source file.

Answer (score 0):

What about `ln -s /usr/bin/youtube-dl ~/bin/dlyoutube`

Comment: That doesn't remove `youtube-dl` from bash completion, unfortunately