# Hide some commands from bash completion?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

In bash, suppose I have these commands:

```
$ pyt[TAB][TAB]
pytest
python
python-config
python-dbg
```

99% of the time, I'd go for `python`. It's so annoying that `pytest` pops up and prevents me from typing only `pyt[TAB][RETURN]` to invoke `python`. Can I hide `pytest` from bash completion?

My limitations:

1. I know that I can remove the `pytest` binary at `/usr/bin/pytest` to prevent that suggestion within bash. But what if I have no root access? What if `pytest` is an important script that must exist in order to let other scripts work properly?
2. Even though I can remove the `pytest` binary (and I've done it before), some time when I upgrade my software, this script comes back again.
3. I know that I can use an `alias` to save keystrokes for my favorite applications (maybe just `p` for `python`). But I don't like these non-standard abbreviations. It kind of makes me confused when I remote to other machines.

So, is there any way to hide some commands from bash completion? Answers in other shells (zsh, fish, etc) are welcome since bash doesn't speed up my workflow lately.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is rather new, but in [Bash 4.4](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/plain/NEWS?id=a0c0a00fc419b7bc08202a79134fcd5bc0427071) you can set the `EXECIGNORE` variable:

> aa. New variable: EXECIGNORE; a colon-separate list of patterns that
>   will cause matching filenames to be ignored when searching for commands.

From [the official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html):

> **EXECIGNORE**
>
> A colon-separated list of shell patterns (see [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching)) defining the list of filenames to be ignored by command search using
>   PATH. Files whose full pathnames match one of these patterns are not
>   considered executable files for the purposes of completion and command
>   execution via PATH lookup. This does not affect the behavior of the [,
>   test, and [[ commands. Full pathnames in the command hash table are
>   not subject to EXECIGNORE. Use this variable to ignore shared library
>   files that have the executable bit set, but are not executable files.
>   The pattern matching honors the setting of the extglob shell option.

For Example:

```
$ EXECIGNORE=$(which pytest)
```

Or using [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
$ EXECIGNORE=*/pytest
```

Comment: Work like a charm!

Comment: See [adding to path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path) for related discussion about appending to a system variable and how to make the variable contents persist upon reboot.

Comment: This isn't an effective answer to the question because programs in EXECIGNORE can't be run at all.

Comment: @durka42 You can still run them using the full path - /usr/bin/pytest will still work in this example.